# Multi select in RecyclerView android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, multi-select

I am trying to implement multi select for `RecyclerView`. I know that it can be easily implemented for `ListView`. I have tried `RecyclerView` MultiSelect

[RecyclerView MultiSelect](https://bignerdranch.github.io/recyclerview-multiselect/)

The problem is I am using a `Fragment` and inside the `Fragment` there is adapter and inside adapter there is the `ViewHolder` Class where all the code is written for selecting the view.

```
MultiSelector mMultiSelector = new MultiSelector();

public class ViewHolder  extends SwappingHolder
        implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    public final View mView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view, mMultiSelector);
        mView = view;
        mView.setLongClickable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (!mMultiSelector.isSelectable()) {
            mMultiSelector.setSelectable(true);
            mMultiSelector.setSelected(ViewHolder.this, true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

But its not working. Is there any way I can implement Muti Select for `RecyclerView` just like `ListView`.

Comment: For Kotlin users, the following article might be useful [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166).

Answer (score 0):

It is not as simple with `RecyclerView` as it is in `listView`.

Try this:
[it is a detailed tutorial for multi select mode with a recyclerView](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/).
I learned from there and it was very helpful, it includes code, and ilustrations

good luck